# AttributeGraph precondition failure: setting value during update when using NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this view:

```
struct PageView: View {
    
    var articulos : [DetallesArticulo]
    var altura : CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        if(articulos.count > 0)
        {
            TabView {

                ForEach(0...articulos.count-1, id: \.self) {i in

                    let vistaTotal = ArticulosViewMinimum()
                    
                    VStack{
                            //Code
                        }.id(UUID())
                }
                .padding(.all, 10)
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: altura)
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

ArticulosViewMinimum is a view like this:

```
class ArticulosViewMinimum: UIView{

    required init(){
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        
        setupViews()

    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
 
    func setupViews(){
        self.addSubview(sampleText)
   }
    
    lazy var sampleText : UITextView = {
        
        let text = UITextView()
        text.attributedText = "sample text".htmlToAttributedString(size: 16, titulo: "")

        return text
    }()
    
}
```

It crashes with the following error message:

> [error] precondition failure: setting value during update: 51768 dyld4
> config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
> DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
> AttributeGraph precondition failure: setting value during update:
> 51768.

And it crashes in my function (extension of string) to convert HTML string to NSAttributedString:

```
func htmlToAttributedString(size: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString? {
    
    var attributedString = NSAttributedString()
    
    if(!self.isEmpty)
    {
        var htmlTemplate = """
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <style>
              body {
                font-family: -apple-system;
                font-size: \(size)px;
              }
            </style>
          </head>
          <body>
            \(self)
          </body>
        </html>
        """

            guard let data = htmlTemplate.data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString()}
                do {
                  attributedString = try NSAttributedString(
                    data: data,
                    options: [
                      .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                      .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
                    ],
                    documentAttributes: nil)
                     
                } catch {}
              }
        
        return attributedString
    }
```

Any idea of what's producing the crash?

Comment: You function works well, at least with simple strings. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: I think the problem is when combining the function with the ForEach or the TabView

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example to debug.

Comment: I edited a simple view that also produces a crash in my project

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved by having another thread to execute the init code. I don't really understand why it works, but it works.

I read that this problem is a swift bug, I hope that in the next update they solve it.

```
class ArticulosViewMinimum: UIView{

required init(){
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    
    self.backgroundColor = .white
    
   DispatchQueue.main.async          //<- Now works
   {
       setupViews()
   }
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews(){
    self.addSubview(sampleText)
}

lazy var sampleText : UITextView = {
    
    let text = UITextView()
    text.attributedText = "sample text".htmlToAttributedString(size: 16, titulo: "")

    return text
}()

}
```